# Answer an UDP packet

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qtnetwork

I have a UDP server using the following code:

```
void initialize() 
{
    connect(&_udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onUdpDatagram()));

    _udpSocket.bind(QHostAddress::Any, 28283);
}

void onUdpDatagram()
{
    qDebug() << "udp packet received!";
    _udpSocket.write("Hello");
}
```

Unfortunately when a UDP packet is received, I have the following error in the log:

```
QIODevice::write: device not open
```

How can I make the UDP socket writable? I tried to create another socket for the answer that connect to the sender address and port but the sending won't use the 28283 port anymore...

Any idea?

For info: I'm using Qt 5.2.1 on MacOS 10.9

Comment: I just use the *writeDatagram()* method instead of the *QIODevice::write()* method as explained. I saw your answer afterward even if you post it before. Thank you for the answer anyway!

Comment: Why would you do that? That is not really portable. If you change the hardware interface to serial, bluetooth, usb, whatever, it will simply get broken. I do not understand what is wrong about the abstract QIODevice interface and write. That is the whole point of C++, it allows proper abstraction. The question was about fixing your code, not scraping that and suggest B instead of A. If you are not interested in getting your code fixed, then just make it clear in the question. I am casting an unclear close vote, sorry.

Comment: My question was not about serial/bluetooth or any abstraction behaviour it is about UDP. But if you want to cast my question as unclear, just let the moderator have a look I'm ready for critics :-)

Comment: I already did because I thought you wanted to fix the code with the current approach, rather than doing a different approach. It misled me, even though I hang around the qt tag a lot. The critic is this: make your question clear that you do not wish to get the current approach fixed (going through QIODevice). Although that would trigger my answer useless now...

Comment: Sorry for that I just read my question and I found it clear: "answer an UDP packet" is quite general no? I wasn't so specific about using QIODevice.

Comment: No, it is not clear. If you post code with approach A, you are expected to get solution for approach A, but getting advices upfront that the whole thing that you are doing wrong. You know, people assume that you are doing something because you want it that way, and not headlessly...

Comment: Yes but also sometimes when you are facing a problem, you need to step back and try a different approach. Nevermind this thread is already to long: let's do the moderator their job if you think it's necessary.

Comment: @FinalContest: The Qt design is defective here: a datagram socket is not interchangeable with a serial link, so having both derive from a common interface doesn't actually lead to being link agnostic.  (The difference is that a datagram socket with a default destination still is a message-oriented pipe, not a byte stream.  If you switch the transport to serial, you would lose the message boundaries that UDP provides.)  And that's just the 1:1 case... a UDP server usually needs to communicate with multiple peers.

Comment: @BenVoigt: you do realize that QIODevice exists for a reason. You can, let me repeat, can replace any hardware interface with any other. In fact, it does not matter on which you send the "Hello World!" through.

Comment: @FinalContest: I realize that is the purpose... and that the Qt design conflates two distinct communication patterns. It would make sense for all message-oriented pipes to share a common interface, and for all byte-oriented pipes to share a common interface. Making those the same is problematic, however. You can replace a UDP link with another packet-switched protocol. You can't replace a UDP link with a TCP link or serial link. Both message-oriented and byte-oriented sockets share part of the API, so it's complicated. And you can put message-framing logic on top of byte-stream to

Comment: create a message-oriented pipe, and there are about a thousand different ways to do message framing.  I'm not understating the challenge of getting both types of interface while at the same time avoiding code duplications.  Nor am I arguing that the advantages of separate interfaces outweigh the need for backward compatibility. But there is a deficiency with the current design, which needs to be accounted for when using it. Pretending it's object-oriented polymorphic nirvana just leads to more problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UDP is not a connection-based protocol.  You don't get a separate socket for each peer, instead there's one socket for all communication on a single port.

Therefore, there's some extra effort needed to reply to an incoming UDP packet.  You need to retrieve the sender address from the datagram you received, and send back to that same address.  In the sockets API this is done by using `recvfrom` and `sendto` functions instead of `recv` (or `read`) and `send` (or `write`) -- the latter are designed for connected sockets like you use with TCP.

You didn't show the declaration (really, the type) for your `_udpSocket` variable, so I'm assuming that you are using a `QUdpSocket`.  In that case, it looks like you will want to use the [`readDatagram`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram) and [`writeDatagram`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram) functions, which like `recvfrom` and `sendto`, have an additional parameter for the peer address (actually, it's a pair, one for the IP address, one for the port).

Here's what the Qt documentation says about that:

> The most common way to use this class is to bind to an address and port using bind(), then call writeDatagram() and readDatagram() to transfer data. If you want to use the standard QIODevice functions read(), readLine(), write(), etc., you must first connect the socket directly to a peer by calling connectToHost().

Comment: This answer only says use "B" instead of "A"; in other words, it does not even bother to target the direction the question took. Moreover, it does not even provide any real code to address the issue, just reiterating the documentation that everyone can read.

Comment: Additionnal question regarding your answer: since I used *QHostAddress::Any* as a binding address, how would I know on which address the received packet has been sent? (since I have various interface)

Answer (score 8):

Coincidentally, [this warning was introduced by me in Qt upstream](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/67257/):

> QIODevice::write: device not open

It should be pretty clear unlike before the introduction of this, namely: you have forgotten to connect to the host with your udp socket. You cannot expect it to write and/or read if it is not even open and/or connected. See the documentation for details:

> If you want to use the standard QIODevice functions read(), readLine(), write(), etc., you must first connect the socket directly to a peer by [calling connectToHost()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost).

You have to do something like this somewhere in your code:

```
_udpSocket.connectToHost(myHostAddress, 28283, ReadWrite, AnyIPProtocol);
```

The last two parameters can be skipped as they are the default. As you can read from the documentation, this method call will open the socket for you, too, which is necessary to get done for `QIODevice` read and write operations.

That being said, you really should not neglect error checking in your code as it currently seems to stand. It will be difficult to find the issues this way.

Also, it is ice on the cake, but I would encourage you to start using the "new" signal-slot syntax, which is not so new, but much more modern and handier:

```
void initialize() 
{    
    connect(&_udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::connected, [&_udpSocket]() {
        connect(&_udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, [&_udpSocket]() {
            qDebug() << "udp packet received!";
            if (_udpSocket.write("Hello") != 6)
                qDebug() << "Failed to write:" << _udpSocket.errorString();
        });
    });
    connect(&_udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::error, [&_udpSocket]() {
        qDebug() << "Error occured:" << _udpSocket.errorString();
    });
    _udpSocket.connectToHost(myHostAddress, 28283, ReadWrite, AnyIPProtocol);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `QHostAddress::Any` with `connectToHost`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I do not think you have read the documentation and/or have tested it. I have done both. Please be more careful when commenting.

Comment: Looks like it is the same as `connectToHost("0.0.0.0", port, mode, proto)` and that will make it all the way to calling the OS `::connect` (in `qt_safe_connect`) which doesn't make any sense either.  On most OSes that is an error.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to `bind()` to `IPADDR_ANY`, which means to receive traffic on all local interfaces.  It makes sense to call `connect()` with the address of a valid peer.  "0.0.0.0" can never be a valid peer, nor even a valid broadcast address, so what should that do?  Set the default destination to a random local interface?  Remove a previously set default destination?  Generate an error?  POSIX doesn't say, and real OSes don't agree.  No, you should never use "0.0.0.0" with `connectToHost()`.